# JetpackCompose - "LocalFocusManager.current.moveFocus()" doesn't work in Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-dialog

I am trying to create a layout of a dialog with two TextFields. In doing so, I am trying to incorporate a feature that when the user completes the upper input field, it will be taken to the next input field by pressing the Next Key. However, it does not work.

In addition, I found out that it worked if not in  Dialog.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TestDialog(
    openDialog: MutableState<Boolean>
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val field1 = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val field2 = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = { openDialog.value = false }
    ) {
        Surface(
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(
                    vertical = 16.dp,
                    horizontal = 16.dp
                ),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Column {
                    Text("Title")

                    Spacer(Spacer)

                    Text(
                        text = "message",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(bottom = 14.dp)
                            .alpha(ContentAlpha.medium),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
                    )

                    OutlinedTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        value = field1.value,
                        onValueChange = { field1.value = it },
                        label = { Text("Label1") },
                        singleLine = true,
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
                        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                            onNext = {
                                //it doesn't work.
                                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                            }
                        )
                    )

                    Spacer(Spacer)
                    
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .fillMaxHeight(0.8f),
                        value = field2.value,
                        onValueChange = { field2.value = it },
                        label = { Text("Label2") }
                    )

                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
                    ) {

                        TextButton(onClick = { openDialog.value = false }) {
                            Text("CANCEL")
                        }

                        TextButton(onClick = {  }) {
                            Text("OK")
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dialog` has its own `LocalFocusManager`.

You have to get its value **inside** the `Dialog`.

```
Dialog(
  onDismissRequest = { false }
){
    //....

    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        value = field1.value,
        onValueChange = { field1.value = it },
        label = { Text("Label1") },
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onNext = {
                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
            }
        )
    )
}
```